# Intersection of vector spaces and inclusion-exclusion

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory, functors

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space.
Let $U,W$ be subspaces of $V$.
Now

$$
\text{dim}(U \cap W) = \text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) - \text{dim}(U + W).
$$

What is the the [category theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) interpretation of that statement, seeing that it looks like the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Principle_of_Inclusion-Exclusion)

$$
\text{card}(U \cup W) = \text{card}(U) + \text{card}(W) - \text{card}(U \cap W)
$$

where $U$ and $W$ are now sets, $\text{card}()$ stands for cardinality, and intersection has been replaced by the union and sum by intersection?

Looks like some functor from finite dimensional vector spaces to $\text{Set}$. Or something.

Related: [A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318311/inclusion-exclusion-for-dimensions-of-specific-vector-spaces) [B](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17740/is-there-a-version-of-inclusion-exclusion-for-vector-spaces)

Comment: The classic proof of $
\text{dim}(U \cap W) = \text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) - \text{dim}(U + W)
$ is to use the vector space basis $V$ and $W$. They are just two sets.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. But I'm wondering if there's something deep going on. I read about the chain complex thing, but maybe there's more.